# JSON files being bundled even though they are not used

Tags: webpack

I've been following the Webpack 4 getting started tutorial with mostly success, but I'm having trouble with the bundle including JSON files that are not actually being included anywhere in the code.

I am using axios to make an ajax request to the json files as needed.  These are static files and I'm using copy-webpack-plugin to copy the json files to the dist folder.  The only place the files are mentioned is in the axios.get() call.

However, when I build, the JSON files are included in dist/index.js.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by moving the JSON files outside of the `src` directory.

BEFORE:

```
/
  src/
    js/
    json/
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

AFTER:

```
/
  data/
    json/
  src/
    js/
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

And modified the copy-webpack-plugin config to copy `data` to the `dist` folder at build time.